# What is the difference between :file and :saveas

Tags: save, scratch-buffer

Both `:file` and `:saveas` seem to change the name of the buffer without writing.  What's the difference between them?  Also, in scratch buffers, `:saveas` seems to cause an error while `:file` does not.  I included the relevant help sections below, but need some help making sense of them.

```
CTRL-G    or        *CTRL-G* *:f* *:fi* *:file*    
              *:file_f*
:f[ile][!] {name} Sets the current file name to {name}.  The optional !
      avoids truncating the message, as with |:file|.
      If the buffer did have a name, that name becomes the
      |alternate-file| name.  An unlisted buffer is created
      to hold the old name.

:sav[eas][!] [++opt] {file}
      Save the current buffer under the name {file} and set
      the filename of the current buffer to {file}.  The
      previous name is used for the alternate file name.
      The [!] is needed to overwrite an existing file.
      When 'filetype' is empty filetype detection is done
      with the new name, before the file is written.
      When the write was successful 'readonly' is reset.
      {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:saveas` does write to files, after all the help says: "*Save* the current buffer under the name {file}". Note also how it says that `!` is needed to overwrite an existing file. You wouldn't need to talk about overwriting if writing wasn't involved.

Also, note the message from a successful `saveas` command:

```
"bar" [New] 364L, 1060C written
```

Answer (score 1):

`:saveas` is not going to work in a scratch buffer. A scratch buffer is a temporary buffer, that is not associated with a file and therefore cannot be saved. Instead they are discarded without warning, when vim is exited.

If you would like to know more:

`:h special-buffers`

`:h buftype`